# Constraint Time Picker in React Native

Tags: react-native

I have a time picker set up as:

```
import TimePicker from 'react-native-simple-time-picker';
class CartScreen extends React.Component {
 state = {
   selectedHours: 0,
   selectedMinutes: 0,
 render() {
   const { selectedHours, selectedMinutes } = this.state;
  <TimePicker
    selectedHours={selectedHours}
    selectedMinutes={selectedMinutes}
    onChange={(hours, minutes) => this.setState({ selectedHours: hours, 
    selectedMinutes: minutes })}/>
       );
    }
 }
```

I was wondering, is it possible to only display or let users pick the time past the current time on the phone? Aka, if it is 3:20 PM, it wont show the options of 12 AM to 3:20 PM, only after the current time.